# Performing centrality analysis with sDNA using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, sdna, unicodedecodeerror

I am trying to perform centrality analysis with sDNA with ArcGIS Pro (ver. 2.7.1). However, I have failed to run the Preparation & Integral Analysis in sDNA with the same reason.

What is the problem and What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Although error messages can be misleading, this sounds like you have a character in your file or file name that does decode to ASCII. Maybe a broken bar instead of a regular bar/pipe character?

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying the sdna arcgis pro plugin newly released this week :) As danak says this looks like an issue caused by non-ascii characters in your data, probably in the field names. I will file it as a bug however in the interim I suggest running sdna with file paths and data in the ascii character set only i.e. English language characters.

Comment: I used the tutorial example file provided in sDNA website for the try-out. It only has the ascii characters

Comment: Please remember to always include the actual command and error message(s) in the body of the question as text (which makes them both legible and searchable).